# Syntax: PostgreSQL with lateral join to stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, join, lateral-join

PostgreSQL 11.1

Where I have a procedure defined as:

```
FUNCTION Copy_Name( to_keep_id integer, to_delete_id integer, parent_table text) RETURNS VOID
```

Can I use it with a cte like:

```
WITH _in (to_keep_name, to_del_name) AS (
    VALUES ('tom', 'bob')
),
_to (keep_name_id, del_name_id)  AS (
    SELECT keep_name.id, del_name.id
    FROM _in
    JOIN tempA keep_name ON (keep_name.name = _in.to_keep_name)
    JOIN tempA del_name ON  (del_name.name = _in.to_del_name)
)
SELECT * 
FROM _to
JOIN LATERAL Copy_Name(_to.keep_name_id, _to.del_name_id, 'tempA') ON true;
```

Is there a preferred syntax for joins to a procedure?

Comment: Your function returns `VOID`.  Why would you want to use it in a query?  That doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just trying to run the stored procedure alongside the cte. (It does work btw). Note: The stored procedure operates on related files. I don't need any output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Using such function in a query makes sense to call it N times with the values produced by the query. It's a bit of an abuse of SQL for the side effects, but it works. A couple of other things in the question don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html)*** cannot be nested in outer queries *at all*.

But I see a ***[function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html)*** here, and no procedure. Since it returns **`void`**, you can just place it in the `SELECT` list, remove the CTE and since you "don't need any output" your query burns down to something like:

```
SELECT copy_name(keep_name.id, del_name.id, 'tempA')
FROM   tempA keep_name
JOIN   tempA del_name ON keep_name.name = 'tom'
                     AND del_name.name = 'bob';
```

Returns a NULL value for each function call. (The effective cross-self-join seems odd, though.)

Else you'd need a **`LEFT JOIN`** to make sense:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _to
LEFT JOIN LATERAL copy_name(_to.keep_name_id, _to.del_name_id, 'tempA') ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Aside: Postgres 11.1? See https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to make it a CROSS JOIN and then drop the `ON true`.  Or just use a comma join.

In this case the LATERAL is a noise word, as function calls are implicitly lateral.  I would probably drop that as well, unless I thought in the future I (or whoever is reading the code) will not now about this feature.  If I were writing for coding amateurs to read, I might keep it.